# IEEEtran and TikZ subfigures over two columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, ieeetran

I have multiple images produced by TikZ and I want to span them on 2 columns.
The IEEEtran documentation says that I should use the `figure` environment to get figures spanning 2 columns. I tried it with graphics (pdf files) and it works perfectly. When I try to do the same thing with TikZ graphics, everything gets messed up.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, calc, fit, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./gfx/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} %[cmex10]
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Authors list}
              \IEEEauthorblockA{My Institution}}
\maketitle


\begin{figure*}
    %\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 1}
        \label{fig:ex1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 2}
        \label{fig:ex3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 3}
        \label{fig:ex3}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Delete or comment out blank lines and spaces between `subfigure` environments.

Comment: You have to be joking ... it worked!

Comment: If the journal gets accepted convert your images to PDF files. IEEE doesn't compile TikZ pictures but gets screenshots and pastes them. Unbelievable but true.

Answer (score 6):

Don't leave blank lines between the `subfigure` environments; a blank line is `\par` so the next `subfigure` will start a new paragraph; between the subfigure environments you can issue `\hfill`, for example, since the total width of the environments is `.9\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, calc, fit, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./gfx/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} %[cmex10]
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Authors list}
              \IEEEauthorblockA{My Institution}}
\maketitle


\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 1}
        \label{fig:ex1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 2}
        \label{fig:ex2}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P1) at (1,2) {$P_1$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P2) at (2,1) {$P_2$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P3) at (1,0) {$P_3$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P4) at (0,1) {$P_4$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P5) at (1,1) {$P_5$};
        \node[circle, fill=gray!30] (P6) at (3,1) {$P_6$};

        %links
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P1);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P2);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P3);
        \draw[-] (P5) -- (P4);
        \draw[-] (P2) -- (P6);

        %dashed rectangles
        \node (B1) [draw=red, dashed, thick, fit= (P1) (P2) (P3) (P4) (P5), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, red] at (B1.south) {};
        \node (B2)  [draw=blue, dashed, thick, fit= (P2) (P5) (P6), rounded corners] {};
        \node [yshift=-1.5ex, blue] at (B2.south east) {}; %yshift=-3.0ex, 

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Example 3}
        \label{fig:ex3}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, perhaps a type, but you are using `\label{fig:ex3}` for subfigures two and three; make sure to change one of them (as I did in my example) to avoid duplicated labels and undesired side-effects.

Comment: @FearUs No, it's not ridiculous; I've added the explanation to my answer: a blank line is equivalent to `\par`, so the next `subfigure` starts a new paragraph; in particualr, is placed on a new line.